# Create a draft mode to wordpress of existing website without make it invisible to public

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. I have to work on this website already nicely made. As I have little experience and the site needs to be always visible, How can I create a **Draft** version of the website to work on it without touching the already existing one.

Comment: Do you mean a draft post? Are you trying to edit the site, or just edit the content?

Answer (score 0):

Make drafts, Make Pages that are privacy: hidden (admin only)

Or make an entirely new website. Mod rw to directory when done.